Connect-OrganizationAddInService using Entra ServicePrincipal ID
Just trying to find if someone has successfully done this, basically automatize the deployment of an Add-in to Office 365
MSOffice Entra ID Token
Client Secret: "1111111111111111111" (This is a secret that should be protected and not shown, I am having a look how to improve this)
APP ID: "2222222222222222222222222"
TenantID : "333333333333333333333333"

I tried the below, but not working
Install-Module -Name O365CentralizedAddInDeployment
Import-Module -Name O365CentralizedAddInDeployment

$clientSecret = "1111111111111111111" 
$appId = "2222222222222222222222222"
$tenantId = "333333333333333333333333"

$secureStringPwd = $clientSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$psCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList
$appId, $secureStringPwd

##Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCredential -Tenant $tenantId ## For Testing   and worked

Connect-OrganizationAddInService -Credential $psCredential

I was expecting to at least  connect to the service.

Are you running as an Admin?  Try starting PS by right click on shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Hi jdweng, I am an admin and I am running PS as Admin

Is there any special role or policy that the ServicePrincipal Entra App needs to be added for the Connecting to the Organization Addin Service?

Can you share the SS of error what you are getting?

I did a couple of changes //Added Office 365 Exchange and ManageAsAPP role to the app //in Permissions In Microsoft Entra roles and administrators added MSOfficeAddon Princial App //

@Pratik I am sure that the secret, app id and tenantid are correct, now I have Connect-OrganizationAddInService : The user name or password is incorrect. Verify your user name, and then type your password again.

Other error: Connect-OrganizationAddInService : The Organization Add-In Service session was not initialized. Please call the Connect-OrganizationAddInService commandlet first

Check Event Viewer on server for any error messages.  Also check Task Manager to make sure server is running.

@jdweng I do no exactly understand why to check event viewer events or any server running, this is against Microsoft O365 Centralized Add In Deployment services, using O365 creds

If I use the same creds with an interactive Microsoft 0365 session those works
